# Path problem when mount Google Drive in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I have successfully mounted Google Drive into Google Colab.
Now I try to copy a file from Drive to Google Colab, but I see an error:`cp: cannot stat 'MyDrive/lab2/methods_Nd.py': No such file or directory`
But that file exists on the Drive.
The commands I use are:

```
# Mount Google Drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

!cp MyDrive/lab2/methods_Nd.py methods_Nd.py
```

If someone had a similar problem, I will be glad to know the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the right place to ask questions.

Comment: Possibly the most unhelpful answer on SO